# Vue 3: Set property value to Modal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a button as follows:

```
<template>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary er fs-6 px-8 py-4"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    :data-bs-target="`#${modalId}`"
  >
    {{ buttonText }}
  </button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "modal-card",
  props: {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    buttonText: String,
    image: String,
    modalId: String,
    accountId: String,
  },
  components: {},
});
</script>
```

Clicking it opens a Modal component as defined by `:data-bs-target`="`#${modalId}`"

How do I set in that Modal Component the value of `accountId`? I tried through a property but not sure how to set it when using `:data-bs-target`

thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the button to having both the :data-bs-target and the @click as follows (which apparently works)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#kt_modal_1" @click="settings(item)">
```

and the modal I just pasted at the top of the page:

```
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="kt_modal_1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title {{ currentItem.id }}</h5>
```

The settings function sets the currentItem:

```
 settings(item) {
      this.currentItem = item;
    },
```